# Wild card usage in XML

Tags: xml, filter, db2, wildcard

Need to filter all values containing B in it from a DB2 table.
(We use a tool that links XML with DB2)

When i use `"B*"` it filters all values that has `B` as first character but when i give `"*B*"` it takes all values in database

`<DESC VALUE ="*B*">` is not working

Is there any other way to prefix a wildcard character for searching elements.

Comment: Which "tool that links XML with DB2"? It may not support wildcards like `*B*`. Or, maybe all rows contain the letter `B`?  You really haven't provided anywhere near enough information for anybody to help.  Show some sample data selected by the query.

Answer (score 1):

I second Peter, use '%B%' see [Wildcards in DB2 SQL](http://bytes.com/topic/db2/answers/880637-wildcards-db2-sql)

> Ofcourse DB2 supports wildcard chars,
>
> use % with LIKE clause in case to CHAR datatype
>
> for eg.
>
> **SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_column LIKE '%1234%'**
>
> this will search matches for substring 1234 anywhere in the string &
>   you will get result as desired: 1234 1234AB 1234ABCD AB1234CD

also

[Basic SQL Coding for DB2 Universal Database for OS/390](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=32101) (under 'Searching for String Patterns);

> SQL has a powerful predicate that allows you to search for patterns in
>   character string columns. This is the LIKE predicate. Suppose you want
>   to generate a list of the candidates whose first name starts with the
>   letter G.
>
> ```
> SELECT fname,lname,wphone,hphone FROM candidate
> WHERE fname LIKE 'G%' ORDER BY lname,fname
> ```
>
> In this query, we use a wildcard character with the LIKE predicate. In
>   SQL, the percent character (%) is a substitute for zero or more
>   characters. The search string G% can be substituted with names like
>   George, Gary, Ginger, and so on (since the percent character can
>   substitute zero or more characters, the search string can also be a
>   single letter G).
>
> The percent character can be used any place in the search string. It
>   also can be used as many times as you need it. The percent sign is not
>   case-sensitive, so it can take the place of uppercase or lowercase
>   letters. However, the constant characters included in your search
>   string are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
select yourcolumn from yourtable where yourcolumn like '%B%'
```

I have no idea about your XML-Tool but maybe this vould lead to a solution for you?